# Finding last pts number from who using grep or awk

Tags: regex, bash, awk, grep, tty

I'm trying to find the value after "pts/" with this output from `who`:

```
someUsersome        tty7         2019-05-09 00:19 (:0)
someUsername        pts/0        2019-05-11 19:11 (:0)
someUsername        pts/4        2019-05-11 19:25 (:0)
someUsername        pts/5        2019-05-11 19:25 (:0)
someUsername        pts/6        2019-05-11 19:25 (:0)
```

I'm close with using `tail` to get the last line, but how do I get just the number after "pts/" only (i.e. no unnecessary white space) which I assume could be any number, perhaps even sometimes higher than a single digit?

I've fiddled with `grep -o` but can't get the matching right because of the date:

`who | tail -n1 | grep -oP 'pts/\K.*'`

Comment: Use `[0-9]*` instead of `.*`

Comment: Ah! Great. Thanks!